# SAP B1 (HANA) Link sales order quantity to volume discount

Tags: hana, sapb1

I have an existing query I am using within Excel to return sales order lines and their corresponding price list, discounts etc.

I need to extend this to show the corresponding volume discount where applicable. I have added a join to my query:

```
left join spp2 T7
  on        T7."CardCode" = T0."CardCode"
  and       T7."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode"
  and       T7."Amount" < T1."Quantity"
```

this links my BP and `ItemCode` from the Order header and line tables. Selecting the `Amount` and `Price` fields from the SPP2 field then returns all lines that match the third line of the Spp2 table.

This means for instance that where I have a sales order line with a quantity of 120, then two price breaks within `SPP2` (50 and 100 for example), will return lines for both the 50 and 100 Volume quantities. I only want to return the line for 100 as that is the one that is being used in the price on the sales order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function row_number(). Add `row_number over ( partition by t7."CardCode", t7."ItemCode" order by t7."Amount" )row_num`to your select clause and filter on `row_num = 1` later.

Or you can add a correlated subquery with `not exists` to your where clause to filter out all spp2 entries where another spp2 entries exists that is closer to t1."Quantity".

Comment: Hi, thank you for the update. I have tried to add the query  I am using below but it is telling me to use less characters. 
Are you able to elaborate on your Subquery please? thanks in advance, Ken